# Openstack Instances cant communicate or ping the subnet the controller and compute is on

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

For some reason i am not able to ping from an instance to the subnet the controller and compute's are on. The network is pretty simple.

VM's/Instances: 10.10.2.0/24
Controller/Compute's: 10.10.1.0/24
The routers external gateway is 10.10.1.4 which I can ping from the instances. Ant help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @schap, to get help you are going to have to give a little more information. Maybe draw your situation so that people get a picture of what you are trying to achieve. Normally it makes sense that you seperate your controller and compute's network from client subnets.

Comment: I understand that you have an external network that maps to 10.10.1.0/24. Can you add the output of `openstack network show NAMEOFYOUREXTERNALNETWORK` and `openstack subnet show NAMEOFYOUREXTERNALSUBNET` to the question? And how did you configure that external network? Please share your agent configuration (usually Linuxbridge agent or Openvswitch agent).

Comment: Thank you for your help! How can I post longer then the characters allowed here?

Comment: admin_state_up UP availability_zone_hints availability_zones  nova description dns_domain  None id 7e0a7235-bbf5-4717-be04-191d877e8cb6 ipv4_address_scope None ipv6_address_scope None  is_default  False  is_vlan_transparent None  mtu  1500  name LabNetport_security_enabled  True project_id a962497a7c064c96b7134b5c1ca150c9 provider:network_type flat provider:physical_network | extnet provider:segmentation_id  | None qos_policy_id  None revision_number 6 router:external External  segments  | None shared True  status ACTIVE subnets 60520868-e8a6-47fa-b861-b892a2d365cf